# Is krypton gas more energy-efficient that low-e argon?

Tags: windows

This company I am about to buy windows from is giving me triple-pane windows with krypton gas for the same price as double-pane with low-e argon.  The salesperson brought some window samples to my house last week to show how krypton gas stops the heat from a heat lamp from passing through.  He held the heat lamp to the regular sample and I felt the heat instantly when I put my hand under the sample.  He switched to the krypton sample and I felt absolutely no heat at all.

I want to go for the triple-pane, but the president of my condo's association is pushing Pella windows really hard.  He argues that krypton gas might have kept me from feeling the heat from the lamp for a few minutes, but, eventually, the heat would have gotten through just the same.

His argument boils down to krypton not being all that it's sold to be, that's it's just a gimmick.  I'd like to hear other people's answers on this.

Comment: How can you compare double pane to a triple pane window?  Of course there will be less heat transfer with the triple pane.

Comment: I don't think the panes themselves offer much heat insulation.  The salesperson told me that, due to the density of krypton, it only works effectively in tighter space.  Three panes creates two separately-isolated areas, perfect for krypton.  This is why they don't sell krypton with double-pane windows.

Comment: A [low e coating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_emissivity#Low-emissivity_windows) on the glass is going to make the difference when it comes to a heat lamp test. The gas in the windows shouldn't effect IR based heat. I'm guessing you were comparing apples to oranges in a marketing gimmick. If you want to compare the gases, pull out a heat gun or blow torch and watch the salesman's face.

Comment: I would only consider such fancy windows once I'd done *every* other possible form of tightening up the house. The difference between the fancy and the super-fancy windows are completely swamped by, say, having a 1/4" air gap somewhere in your unit. If you were building the perfect green sealed home it might matter, but for normal construction...don't get sucked into the hype.

Comment: Four feet of insulation in your attic would have a higher R value than one foot, but the optimal is what you are looking for. Pella went to insulated glass very late in the game. PVC is PVC it doesn't matter the name brand. What does matter is the gauge of the vinyl extrusion. .050 gauge is builder grade. .060gauge is good. .080 is the heaviest and generally imported from a german extruder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As someone who bought new windows a couple years ago and researched it to death, almost anything a window salesmen tells you will be a marketing gimmick.

The fact of the matter is that when it comes to heat transfer resistance with windows, you reach the point of diminishing returns rather quickly.

Triple pane windows will give you a slight advantage in energy efficiency however they tend to be heavier and far more expensive.  The extra weight can often cause them to wear out the casing or unseat over time however.  Now consider comparing these to dual pane windows with a low E coating and you will only see a slight drop in resistance from the window itself.

Both Krypton and Argon are noble gases and both achieve the same effect, they insulate between 2 or more panes of glass by slowing down the transfer of heat.  Krypton is typically used in triple pane where Argon is typically used in double pane and this has to do with the maximum heat transfer resistance for each gas at different widths between panes of glass.

Krypton does in fact do slightly better but usually at an enormous upfront cost that in my opinion would be hard to get ROI on over the years as compared to dual pane low E Argon windows.  Over time with the expansion and contraction of the casing and general exposure to the elements, microscopic stress fractures will start forming around the case slowly allowing all that expensive Krypton or Argon gas to escape, essentially making the windows lose heat transfer resistance over time.  Investing in a window with a better quality case design will do more to improve the overall energy efficiency of your windows than any investing in triple pane Krypton.

A good quality case design that is well insulated and uses high quality weather resistant vinyl will do more to increase the lifespan of the windows and maintain the energy efficiency of the windows by being more resistant to leaks and fractures that will result in the slow seepage of the noble gases.

It can be hard to seperate the gimmicks from the truth when it comes to window shopping, so thoroughly understanding the difference is important.  Figure out what your monthly heating bill is and use that as a basis for making a good decision.  If you are living in the Yukon and you have long frigid winters then perhaps spending the extra money for the triple pane krypton windows is worth it.

Comment: Good answer.  In my experience with windows, the argon leaks much faster than people would expect.

Answer (score 2):

All things being equal (airspace, glass, spacer) Krypton is more efficient than Argon.  Krypton works better when the airspace is reduced.  However that does not mean that it is less efficient than Argon.   Its not a gimmick. Read this [Article](http://windowguru.wordpress.com/2014/08/29/air-vs-argon-vs-kyrpton-vs-xenon).   It has a chart showing the airspace and Argon / Krypton efficiencies. Even Xenon!

Triple glazing may or may not more efficient than if the overall sealed unit is the same then they are less efficient.  Double glazed with (3mm + 1/2" air space w/ argon + 3mm) is more efficient than a triple (3mm + 3/16 air space w/argon + 3mm + 3/16 air space w/argon 3mm).   With the 3/16 air spaces argon is close to useless.  This is why some manufactures put Krypton in.  Its because the triple is so bad with the argon that the only way you can achieve better ratings is to add Krypton.

If you can get larger triples like 1 3/8" sealed units they will perform incredibly and there is no need for Krypton.

Today a double glazed w/ low E & argon is pretty much all you need. The ROI on krypton or triples is pretty low.  Triples are good for sound insulation.   If you live in extreme cold temperatures like in Yellowknife triples is probably a must.

Answer (score 0):

Triple pane is 60% more efficient than a double pane. Krypton gas is significantly more effective than Argon. That is why these properties cost more.

If you are getting it for the same price as double either the Double provider is High or the Triple provider is Low (or an efficient manufacturer). The thickness of the PVC matters, as does the glass itself- some use 3 mm builder grade instead of 4 mm.

With 15 different metrics to measure windows, simple radiation of heat measured by a BTU meters DOES in fact make comparison of 3 vs. 2 glaze possible. And a Triple glaze gives you better Noise reduction and less Condensation.

Answer (score 0):

The facts are Krypton is twice the mass of Argon and twice the size.  It takes more energy to get the Krypton gas elements moving in a convection between the panes of glass.  Therefore more time is needed to transfer the radiant heat from one pane of glass to the next. 
This time advantage works because it is significant. More than four times as long as Argon. Krypton is better than Argon simply be the chemistry and the physics of the triple glass.
I like the use of Xenon as a potential gas for windows.  Xenon is over three times the mass of Argon. I would imagine Xenon is more rare than the other two so likely more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Using Triple pane window glass with 5/16" spacers + 1/8" annealed glass (total thickness of 1 inch) with Low-E3 and Krypton Gas, it is possible to get a R-Value of 12.5 (U-value = 0.08) -- almost the same R-value as your walls (R-13 on new homes).

Using double pane window glass Low-E3 even going to a 1/2" spacer (total thickness of 3/4") via Cardinal Glass with their best glass U-value = 0.25 or R-Value = 4.000, or less than a 1/3 the efficiency of the triple pane krypton window glass.

To get the best argon window glass, you need to go to triple pane (Cardinal XL Edge IG) 1 3/8" (two 1/2 inch spacers with low-3e and argon) for a U-value of 0.11 or R-Value of 9.091 or 72% the efficiency of triple pane krypton window glass. Note it would also be a lot harder to find a window manufacturer with a IGU window spacing 1 3/8" vs 3/4" or 7/8" or 1" in their new construction or replacement window frame.

All widths using annealed (aka double-strength glass that is actually 4 times stronger than single-strength glass).